# Is it allowed to have 2 go.mod in one repository?

Tags: go, github

My goal is to create a package that can be used in other projects with:

1. `$ go get github.com/${username}/${repositoryname}`
2. `$ go get github.com/${username}/${repositoryname}/${subpackage}`.

The problem is that the `examples` folder use `go-pretty` to preview the output. The package does not need `go-pretty` to run.

The project layout:

```
|-examples
| |-api
|   |-main.go
| |-filepath
|   |-main.go
|-pdftotext
| |-pdftotext.go
|-texttoparsed
| |-texttoparsed.go
|-go.mod
|-go.sum
```

What I've did:

1. Init `$ go mod init github.com/kidfrom/e-statement-to-t-account`
2. Install `$ go get github.com/jedib0t/go-pretty/v6` and `$ go get github.com/jedib0t/go-pretty/v6/table`

Comment: A module only has a single `go.mod` file. `go.mod` has nothing to do with compiling the packages, it only declares dependencies. Unused code is not linked into your binary.

Comment: <https://go.dev/ref/mod#module-path>

Comment: It's perfectly legal for a git repo to contain more than one `go.mod` file spread across different directories. It only makes practical sense to do so, if you want the consumer of your packages to pin different versions of these packages. Don't obsess about fringe imports - if they are not used, they will not be used in client builds.

Comment: Note that the module name in the go.mod file on Github does not match the actual path of the repository.  Fix the name before debugging further.

Comment: @CeriseLimón I tried to fix it by modifying the `go.mod` manually, changing it to `module github.com/kidfrom/e-statement-to-t-account` and push it to the repository. However, when I tried to do `$ go get github.com/kidfrom/e-statement-to-t-account` again, the error persisted `module declares its path as: github.com/e-statement-to-t-account
                but was required as: github.com/kidfrom/e-statement-to-t-account`. I tried to do `go clean -modcache`, still no luck.

Comment: @kidfrom: `go clean -modcache` does not remove the module from the global proxy. Push a new version, `go get` the exact commit you want, wait until the proxy picks up the latest commit, or use `GOPROXY=direct` temporarily.

Comment: @JimB Noted. `go get github.com/kidfrom/e-statement-to-t-account@e58f5294672f69f98123e3cdde610f12e21dc9fb` does the job. Anyway, `Push a new version`, do you mean do `$ git tag`?

Comment: Tags are generally used for versions, but see https://go.dev/ref/mod#vcs-version for details.